# Route not defined in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 304: Route [customer.signup] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomm\app\Modules\Templates\Resources\Views\layouts\public.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomm\app\Modules\Templates\Resources\Views\layouts\public.blade.php)

but as far as I know my routes is all correct.
My public.blade.php

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> User Management <span class="caret"></span>   </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="{!! route('customer.signup') !!}">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

my routes

```
Route::get('/shipping-info', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@shippingInfo',
    'as' => 'cart.shippingInfo'
]);

Route::get('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@signup',
    'as' => 'customer.signup'
]);

Route::delete('/product/deleting/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@deleting',
    'as' => 'deleting'
]);

Route::get('/login', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@login',
    'as' => 'client.login'
]);

Route::get('/shopping-cart', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@shoppingCart',
    'as' => 'cart.shop'
]);

Route::get('/product/update-item/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@updateProduct',
    'as' => 'cart.update'
]);

Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@index',
    'as' => 'index',
]);

Route::get('/{id}', 'OpenController@content');

Route::get('gallery/{title}', 'OpenController@galleryCategory');

Route::get('/product/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@product',
    'as' => 'shop.product'
]);

Route::post('/product/update-cart/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@updateCart',
    'as' => 'cart.updateCart'
]);

Route::put('/product/update-qty/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@newQty',
    'as' => 'new.qty'
]);
```

My signup method in OpenController

```
public function signup()
{
    echo "OpenController Signup";
}
```

Comment: hi Nix, i wonder if your route is enclosed within middleware or prefix..?

Comment: Can you post the top part of the controller as well? Namespace, classname etc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear your route cache, if you've already run `route:cache` before:

```
php artisan route:clear
```